An Interesting Air Resistance Problem
Below is a question from my class notes from the topic $1$D Kinematics:

A ball is thrown vertically upwards with an initial speed $v_0$. Air resistance is given by $\vec{a_{res}}=-k\vec{v}$ where $k\in R^+$ and $\vec{v}$ is the velocity of the ball at any instant. Let $t_1$ and $t_2$ be its time of ascent and the time of descent respectively. Then, what can be concluded about that ratio $t_1:t_2$?

My approach:
Say $v$ denotes the component of the velocity of the ball along the vertical direction, i.e., the ball's speed with sign and displacement, velocity, acceleration are taken positive in the upward direction. For $t_1$,
$$-(g+kv)=\frac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm dt}$$
$$\implies -\int_{v_0}^0\frac{\mathrm dv}{g+kv}= \int_0^{t_1}\mathrm dt$$
$$\implies t_1=\frac1{k}\ln\left(1+\frac{kv_0}{g}\right)$$
Let $h$ be the maximum height. Then while going upwards,
$$-(g+kv)=\frac{v\mathrm dv}{\mathrm dx}$$
$$\implies-k\int_0^h\mathrm dx=\int_{v_0}^01-\frac{g}{g+kv}\mathrm dv$$
$$\implies kh=v_0-\frac{g}{k}\ln\left(1+\frac{kv_0}{g}\right)$$
$$\implies h=\frac{kv_0-g\ln\left(1+\frac{kv_0}{g}\right)}{k^2}$$
For $t_2$ where $u$ denotes the speed of the ball just before reaching the ground,
$$-g+kv=\frac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm dt}$$
$$\implies \int_0^{-u}\frac{\mathrm dv}{kv-g}=\int_{t_1}^{t_1+t_2}\mathrm dt$$
$$\implies t_2=\frac1{k}\ln\left(1+\frac{ku}{g}\right)$$
$$\implies u=\frac{g}{k}\left(e^{kt_2}-1\right)$$
Since the distance covered while going upwards and downwards is the same, i.e., $h$, hence while going donwards:
$$-g+kv=\frac{v\mathrm dv}{\mathrm dx}$$
$$\implies k\int_h^0\mathrm dx=\int_0^{-u}1-\frac{g}{g-kv}\mathrm dv$$
$$\implies -kh=-u+\frac{g}{k}\ln\left(1+\frac{ku}{g}\right)$$
$$\implies -kh=\frac{g}{k}\left(1-e^{kt_2}\right)+gt_2$$
$$\implies e^{kt_2}-1-kt_2=\frac{kv_0}{g}-\ln\left(1+\frac{kv_0}{g}\right)$$
Let $f(t)=e^{kt}-kt-1\implies f'(t)=k\left(e^{kt}-1\right)\ge 0\text{ }\forall\text{ }t\ge 0$. Viz., $f(x)$ is increasing $\forall\text{ }t\ge0$. By observation,
$$f(t_1)=1+\frac{kv_0}{g}-\ln\left(1+\frac{kv_0}{g}\right)-1=f(t_2)$$
$$\therefore {t_1:t_2=1}$$
I solved this question using this approach at home, not in class as it was getting quite lengthy(I was able to solve till $t_2$ in terms of $u$ only). In class, my teacher explained that in high school Physics, such in-depth mathematical treatment is not required, so qualitatively it can be seen that as the ball goes up, the magnitude of its acceleration, $g+kv$, is more than that when it goes down, $g−kv$; so $t_1:t_2<1$. But now, I am getting $t_1:t_2=1$ even after checking my answer many times. Can someone kindly point out my mistake(s)? Or is there any other, perhaps better way to solve this problem?

Maybe you may take another approach: the descending ball will have, due to air resistance, after some time (and distance) a constant velocity. What vertically upwards initial speed is required to push it so high? The idea is to look at extremas to check the ansatz.

@m-stgt can you please suggest how do I approach in a different way? And as far as terminal velocity is concerned, it will be attained at infinity, so how does that help?

Maximum velocity is attained when $g+k\vec{v}=0$, in other words, when the ball is not accelerated. Your teacher should have explained that, me think.

@m-stgt Yes, I know that. Had the ball started with rest in such an environment, its $v-t$ graph would have a horizontal asymptote $v=\frac{g}{k}$. And I can't understand what extrema are you talking about. Can you please elaborate?

With extrema I mean to look at exceptional situations, if for that cases your ansatz still returns reasonable results. For example no air resistance, will the initial velocity be the same as the final (with oposite diretion). What happens if air resistance is ~$v^2$, at what $v_0$ will the ball not fall back (first approach w/o air resistance), if a gun fired upwards, will the bullet falling down be lethal? (Yes, I was told) -- Those extrema might show if your approach is correct or not.

@m-stgt yes I tried taking the limit as $k\to0$ and the values matched.

$$\fbox{$t_2=\frac{g W\left(-\frac{e^{-\frac{k v_0}{g}-1} (g+k v_0)}{g}\right)+g \left(-\log \left(\frac{k v_0}{g}+1\right)\right)+g+k v_0}{g k}\text{ if }g+k v_0>0$}$$
Hence $\frac{t_1}{t_2}\ne 1$.
Hint: $W(z)$ is the Lambert W function or product logarithm.

@gpmath I am in high school, so I don't know much about the Lambert $W$ function. Can you please elaborate on how you solved for $t_2$?

One fundamental error is the equation:
$$-g+kv=\frac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm dt}$$
If we convert it to:
$$\mathrm dv=-k\left ( \frac{g}{k}-v \right )\mathrm dt$$
then we see that $dv<0$ because always $dt>0$.
But as the body falls, its speed increases i.e. $dv>0$
The correct equation is
$$g-kv=\frac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm dt}$$
The solution to this equation is
$$v=\frac{g}{k}\left ( 1- e^{-kt}\right )$$
or if you wish
$$u=\frac{g}{k}\left ( 1- e^{-kt_2}\right )$$
